# parse_str for python?

Tags: php, python

Is there a parse_str (used in php) alternative for python?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php
parse_str — Parses the string into variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urlparse.parse_qs: http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs

If you are using a Python older than 2.6, the previous location of this function was in the cgi module: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.parse_qs

Comment: The problem is ...

    >>> import urlparse
    >>> dir(urlparse)
    ['BaseResult', 'MAX_CACHE_SIZE', 'ParseResult', 'SplitResult', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '_parse_cache', '_splitnetloc', '_splitparams', 'clear_cache', 'non_hierarchical', 'scheme_chars', 'test', 'test_input', 'urldefrag', 'urljoin', 'urlparse', 'urlsplit', 'urlunparse', 'urlunsplit', 'uses_fragment', 'uses_netloc', 'uses_params', 'uses_query', 'uses_relative']

Comment: @vkris: So what? That's everything that's in the module `urlparse`, but Adam already told you which one you need.

Comment: @vkris: What's you Python version? Docs say `parse_qs` was added in 2.6 (which is quite old).

Comment: Have you tried it instead of just checking module definition crap?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python<2.6

`parse_qs` is in the `cgi` module

It's still there in 2.7 for backward compatibility